# jQuery carousel / Gallery not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im new to JS and having real issue cracking a few issues and hope someone could help me out.

1. image not going full size
2. if you resize and click nav goes 100mph and keeps going
3. when you resize its not resizing the images / carousel correctly
4. i tried adding getImageSizes functionto get image size of change and
   set lis but thats not working ether

as i said im very new and this is a new job im on so really need to ge this done today :(

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  //get width of document here and set to li
    setConfig();
    //getImageSizes();

    $(window).resize(function () {
        setConfig();
        //getImageSizes();
    });

    var slideCount, slideWidth, slideHeight, sliderULWidth;

    function setConfig() {
        $('#gallery-slider ul li').css({
            "width": ($(window).width() - 200), "height": $(window).height() - 200
        });

        slideCount = $('#gallery-slider ul li').length;
        slideWidth = $('#gallery-slider ul li').width();
        slideHeight = $('#gallery-slider ul li').height();
        sliderULWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

        $('#gallery-slider').css({
            width: slideWidth,
            height: slideHeight
        });

        $('#gallery-slider ul').css({
            width: sliderULWidth,
            marginLeft: -slideWidth
        });

        $('#gallery-slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#gallery-slider ul');


        $('#gallery-slider a.control_prev').on('click', function () {
            moveLeft();
            return false;
        });

        $('#gallery-slider a.control_next').on('click', function () {
            moveRight();
            return false;
        });
    }

    function getImageSizes() {
        $("#gallery-slider ul li img").each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('#gallery-slider ul li').css({ "width": $this.width(), "height": $this.height() });
            console.log($this.width());
            console.log($this.height());
        });
    }

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#gallery-slider ul').animate({
            left: +slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#gallery-slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#gallery-slider ul');
            $('#gallery-slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    }

    function moveRight() {
        $('#gallery-slider ul').animate({
            right: -slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#gallery-slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#gallery-slider ul');
            $('#gallery-slider ul').css('right', '');
        });
    }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYwPXQ

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed
http://codepen.io/choukroun/pen/OPVBdR

notice that you used in the `moveright()`

`left: +slideWidth`

and in the `moveleft()`

`right: -slideWidth`

It confusing when you use 2 direction usually it's better to use only `left/right`
and for better performance I would sugget that you use `transform: translate`

Comment: Super thanks, do you have any ideas why the image is not full width on desktop for exmaple, it goes smaller as you decrease window size but just starts off to small.... :(

Comment: the height of your li is 296px and the `max-height` of your img is 100% so the height of the img won't be bigger then 296px (on small screen
`"width": ($(window).width() - 200), 
"height": $(window).height() - 200`)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't code that from scratch. There are many jQuery plugins (see [here](http://www.vandelaydesign.com/jquery-image-galleries/) that are doing exactly what you need. For example http://fotorama.io/ is such a plugin. See example below. You can also find that at jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/tqp3yeye/)

Also galleria.io is a good gallery slider. I have used it for a smaller web page in production.

That's a lot easier. Please have a look at the fotorama page for customization (e.g. autoplay, thumbnails, etc.)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.2/fotorama.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.2/fotorama.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="fotorama">
  <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg" />
  <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/2.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Cannot use plugins, hence why coding from scratch :)

Comment: Oh OK, is it a requirement for your project? Any way, maybe it helps to check out their code to see how they solved it.